# Public swift class import "private" module in mixed language(ObjC+Swift) dynamic framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks, swift-framework

I have a dynamic framework `MyFramwork.framework` that has Swift code and  ObjC headers marked as Protected *(to be used internally in MyFramwork.framework)* and Public *(to be used externally by the App)* in the framework's project. Also MyFramwork.framework is an embedded framework in App

Following the steps mentioned here http://nsomar.com/project-and-private-headers-in-a-swift-and-objective-c-framework/, i've created a

```
module MyFramwork_Private {
    header "../...h"
    ...

    export *
}
```

with all protected headers (`SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS` = path to directory where the module.modulemap file is)

and an `PublicHeaders.h`(which i import in my umbrella header `MyFramwork.h`) with all the public headers

**How can I make a Public Swift class/struct that makes use of MyFramwork private code available in App?**

If i `import MyFramwork_Private` in a swift file from MyFramwork, the App, when building the MyFramwork.framework, will try to access the private headers defined in `module MyFramwork_Private` and build fails because App can not see the protected header

Answer (score 5):

I've been struggling with this as well, this is what I found out that did the trick for me:

1. Besides from the steps you have already taken, make sure that you create another modulemap (ex. MyFramework.private.modulemap) in $(SRCROOT)/Myframework and add the following to this file:

   `module MyFramework_Private {
       export *

   }`
2. Edit the following options in your .xcconfig file:

   `SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS    = $(SRCROOT)/MyFramework
   MODULEMAP_PRIVATE_FILE = $(SRCROOT)/MyFramework/MyFramework.private.modulemap`

After this you should be good to go, the app that is using your framework should now have a clear understanding what MyFramework_Private is and your internal Swift files have a way to access the private headers. Let me know how it worked out for you, happy to help if I can.

Comment: I wrote this script, https://gist.github.com/danielpetroianu/11f8c3223c3baf09e551d6998edc8f88 , maybe it help others with objc-swift frameworks to better organise  their public/private headers, it follows the principles that nsomar recomanded

Comment: it didn't work for me ... :(, i get a swiftc error exit 1 bla bla. I will try some more with a small project and work my way up to my project, when I'll have some more time, maybe there is a different problem, that I don't now yet how to read. Currently I just made public the headers (2-3) that I'm interested in.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore. Since both the modules have similar names, it gives an error while compiling: `redefinition of module`

Comment: did you get any solution on this, @nr5